# New entity with preset ID detected as "detached entity"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have an entity `Player` with this ID defintion

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(updatable=false)
private long id;
```

However, sometimes (but not always) I want to create a new instance with a preset ID.

```
player = new Player(...);
player.setId(externalId);
em.persist(player);
```

This apparently causes Hibernate to see it as a detached entity, throwing the exception

> org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I could remove the `@GeneratedValue` and generate IDs myself, something like:

```
begin transaction
if id not preset {
    do {
        id = random number
    } while (id in use)
}
create player with id
commit transaction
```

That should be safe, with the transaction, but it's less optimal than letting the database deal with it.

Comment: or change the "long" to Long. This then allows nulls (i.e unset)

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong there. Could you please tell us why you want a fixed Id ?
Because you're actually saying "please create an ID for me I *NEVER* want to deal with this" then you are sometimes trying to set an ID yourself which probably means you are corrupting the whole thing.

That exception might be because you are setting an ID that is already used. Then when trying to persist, hibernate detects it as out of sync (detached) with what's in DB so he just throws that exception.

Comment: I'm running the same server software twice. In one instance IDs are automatically generated, but in another they are externally supplied (by Facebook, in this case). Btw, the database is empty, so it can't be that the ID was already in use.

Comment: Ok, then it's empty and you are setting an ID which is marked as "auto generated" which means that when you ask your em to persist, it will look at the ID, if null (not set) it will generate a new one and persist your entity. If not null then it will look up in DB to find corresponding entity and update (I THINK, it's been a long time without java for me :P). So, when you set your ID, it looks for an entity that doesn't exist and it tells you your entity is out of synch. (i guess it assumes that your entity has been deleted between your supposed "find()" and "persist()" or something like that)

Comment: Errm, how can a "long" be "unset" (null) ? it can't. it always has a value, whether applied by the compiler or by the user.

Comment: Possibly 0 is seen as unset when dealing with auto-generated IDs.

Comment: I'm replying here cause I guess I don't have enough rep to comment others answers:
You could use some kind of "your side" id that would mean nothing for DB but that would mean everything for you and then set some generation algorythm so you could do anything you want with it. I bet there are very good id generation algorythm out there.
Edit: this comment is pointless, that's actually what you want to do. And I believe this is the right way to go.